# How do I display data from AsyncStorage in a custom component?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native. So, I've a custom component called Task and I've some data stored in AsyncStorage. I've checked that the data is indeed stored in AsyncStorage through another component/modal. But when I'm trying to get that data back from AsyncStorage (see code below), it's not displaying anything. My custom component is otherwise displaying data fine, just is unable to get/display the data from AsyncStorage. Am I doing something wrong here? Please help me.

Inside/called from within render() function:

```
  <Task name={async ()=>await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskname')}
                        desc={async ()=>await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdesc')}
                        date={async ()=>await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdate')}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the stored value in the state value and use it.

```js
this.state={
   name : '';
   desc : '';
   date : '';
}
...

async getdata() {
let taskname =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskname')
let taskdesc =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdesc')
let taskdate =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdate')
this.setState({
   name : taskname;
   desc : taskdesc;
   date : taskdate;
});
}
...
  <Task name={this.state.name}
                        desc={this.state.desc}
                        date={this.state.date}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put this code in componentDidMount and call in return.

```
constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
       name : '';
       desc : '';
       date : '';
     }
   }
 componentDidMount= async()=>{
 let taskname =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskname')
 let taskdesc =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdesc')
 let taskdate =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdate')

 }

 render(){
 return(
 <View>
 <Task name={this.state.name} desc={this.state.desc} date={this.state.date}/>
 </View>
 )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see many solutions here, But you should also add `loading` state, as your Task component will receive empty strings at first.

So the better approach is to add loading until you receive the data.

```
this.state={
   loading: true,
   name : '';
   desc : '';
   date : '';
}

async componentDidMount(){

 let taskname =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskname')
 let taskdesc =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdesc')
 let taskdate =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('taskdate')
 this.setState({ ...set your state here}, () => {
  and then update the loading state.
 })
  }
```

and when the loading is true, you can render a loading component, or null.